# PHP timeout when sending thousands of push notifications

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I have implemented push notifications using service worker and from server I push the notification using the web-push-php library. When I have to send thousands of notifications, PHP timeout will occur. How to prevent this scenario?

Comment: You probably need to use some sort of background worker. You can't send thousands of notifications from the same process of your frontend (web server): you need a separate process. See for example see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313028/jobs-processing-in-background-from-web-application) or search "php sidekiq". Otherwise you can use a service that performs the sending for you: for example if you use Pushpad you can send bulk notifications to thousands of subscribers with just a single HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

In my [WordPress Plugin for Web Push](https://github.com/mozilla/wp-web-push) (unmaintained now) I used curl multi to speed up sending notifications.

Take a look at this class: https://github.com/mozilla/wp-web-push/blob/master/wp-web-push/web-push.php.